# Add a console.log or equivalent from within the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

In e.g., Chrome Dev tools, it is easy to set a breakpoint in the Javascript for a website. When you are stopped at a breakpoint, it is easy to log out the value of any variable in the scope of the breakpoint, and you can even use watch expressions to have this done automatically.

However, what I would like to do is add console logging to a script *from within the browser*, so that I can see values without stopping execution of the script in a breakpoint.

My use case is that when developing, I will often use console logs for debugging. I may add a console log, compile, start my dev server, navigate to the place in the app where the code is executed, and observe the log. However, for my team's workflow, it would be useful to be able to add additional logs without having to recompile etc. Is there a way to do this in Chrome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting at Chrome 73, you can use [Logpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/01/devtools#logpoints), which are basically non-breaking breakpoints which only do logging for you.

Before Logpoints was a thing - you could set a [conditional breakpoint in devtools](https://davidwalsh.name/debugging-conditional-breakpoints) and just write `console.log(someVar)` inside the conditional statement, and it would work since `console.log` doesn't return anything, and hence not stopping at the desired breakpoint.

Comment: console.log at conditional breakpoint is a great trick that I never thought of! I didn't have the most recent version of Chrome with logpoints, but I upgraded and now I do. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do logpoints work with sourcemaps? Chrome seems to be completely ignoring any logpoint I set.

Comment: @Seanonymous They do. If it's not working for you, try refreshing. Also, sometimes breakpoints (any kind of breakpoint) in async functions are a bit problematic - I'm pretty sure it's a webpack thing. But it's supposed to work with Source Maps

Answer (score 4):

Adding a console log is something Google recently add.
In the selected row instead of left click,click right click and select 'add logpoint', a small text box will pop up, enter the variable you want you console log.

If you do not see this feature update your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I accepted the other answer because it was slightly before yours, but I upvoted anyway so you still get some credit.